# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

i have an xml file which contains i.e file.xml

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <authorise  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <value1>{0}</value1>
      <value2>{1}</value2>
    </authorise>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I have a asmx web service which i call like:

```
string[] data = { "Value1", "Value2"};

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Proxy = null;
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); //path to xml file i.e file.xml

    MyData = String.Format(reader.ReadToEnd(), data);
    reader.Close();
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
       delegate(
           object sender1,
           X509Certificate certificate,
           X509Chain chain,
           SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
       {
           return true;
       };

    rst = client.UploadString(new Uri(https://myasmxwebservice.asmx), MyData); //Throws exception from here
}
```

it has been working fine, until i started getting an error 
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.". i do not know the problem, neither do i know how to solve it.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @mason i have updated the post, to indicate where the error occurs

Comment: The line of code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @mason it has been working, all of a sudden it just stopped, i really do not know how to go about this, i am so confused right now

Comment: Look at your question. You haven't provided valid arguments to the Uri constructor. Your code won't compile.

Comment: @mason i have updated the question

Comment: Your code still won't compile. `new Uri(https://myasmxwebservice.asmx)` is not valid C#.